# Transformando uma Tabela 1xN do Sql Server em objeto no C#

Tags: c#, winforms

sou novo no forum e gostaria de uma ajuda. Estou tentando passar uma junção de tabelas com as informações do cliente para o C# mas estou tendo problemas em transformar os campos 1xN em objetos. Quero trazer os campos ID, Nome, Sexo, DDD e Telefone; Sendo que o cliente pode ter mais de um telefone. Meu problema é que quando você faz esse select desse join no SQL server e um cliente possui mais de um telefone, a tabela ira repetir todos os campos e mudar apenas o DDD e telefone. Quando eu Transformo os dados da tabela que pego do banco de dados em uma lista, a lista fica idêntica ao join feito no Windows server. Gostaria de saber como faço para transformar esse segundo DDD e telefone em outro objeto.
Classe de Conexão com o BD:

```
public class AccessBd
    {

        private SqlConnection CreateConnextion()
        {
            return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-T1LNBJO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TESTEOFICINA;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        }
        //Parametros que irão para o banco
        private SqlParameterCollection sqlParameterCollection = new SqlCommand().Parameters;

        public void ParameterCleaner()
        {
            sqlParameterCollection.Clear();
        }

        public void AddParameters(string parameterName, object parameterValue)
        {
            sqlParameterCollection.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterName, parameterValue));
        }

public DataTable ExecuteSelect(CommandType commandType, string spOrText)
        {
            try
            {
                //Criar a conexão
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = CreateConnextion();
                //Abrir Conexão
                sqlConnection.Open();
                //Criar Comando que leva informação para o banco
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                //Colocando as coisas dentro do comando
                sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = spOrText;
                //Tempo máximo que o programa pode tentar executar o comando sql
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 50;
                //Adicionar os parametros no comando
                foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameterCollection)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(sqlParameter.ParameterName, sqlParameter.Value));
                }
                //Criando um adaptador
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                //DataTable -> Tabela de dados Vazia onde vou colocar os dados que vem do banco
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                //Mandar o comando ir até o banco buscar os dados e preencher o datatable
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                return dataTable;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
}
```

Classe que Pega os dados do BD:

```
public class BusinessClients
    {
        List<Clients> clientCollection = new List<Clients>();
        AccessBd AccessBd = new AccessBd();     

        public List<Clients> FillTable()
        {
            try
            {
                //Instancia uma nova coleção de cliente
                List<Clients> clientCollection = new List<Clients>();
                AccessBd.ParameterCleaner();
                //Coloca a consulta dentro do DataTable
                DataTable dataTableCli = AccessBd.ExecuteSelect(CommandType.Text, "SELECT IDCLIENTE, DATACAD, CPF, NOME, SEXO, DDD, NUMERO,TIPO FROM V_CLIENTE");
                //Percorre Cada linha do DataTable, transformando-as em um objeto Client
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTableCli.Rows)
                {
                    //Como o atributo vem do BD com o tipo Object, se faz necessário sua conversão
                    int idCli = Convert.ToInt32(row["IDCLIENTE"]);
                    string nome = Convert.ToString(row["NOME"]);
                    char sexo = Convert.ToChar(row["SEXO"]);                    
                    string ddd = Convert.ToString(row["DDD"]);
                    string numero = Convert.ToString(row["NUMERO"]);
                    clientCollection.Add(new Clients(idCli, nome, sexo, ddd, numero));

                }
                clientCollection.Sort((x, y) => x.NomeCliente.CompareTo(y.NomeCliente));
                return clientCollection;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao Carregar o Banco de dados: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Você fazer queries distintas paras as referências e ou montar um DataSet

Comment: Eu sou bem novato em programação orientada a objeto. Poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu faço a primeira e a segunda opção?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter?redirectedfrom=MSDN